# Is there any difference in meaning between "burn a house" and "burn down a house"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *burn a house* and *burn down a house*? For example:

> The man went crazy and **burned** his house.
>
> The man went crazy and **burned down** his house.

Comment: *Burn down* implies that the house is 'destroyed'.

Comment: *down* stresses the completeness/extremeness of the action. If you burn a house down, you destroy it with fire completely, beyond repair; you burn it to the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most native speakers would not say 'burn a house' even if just one part was burnt ('burned' in US English). If a house is destroyed by fire it is burnt/burned **down**.

Comment: could "he burned his house" mean he started a fire, or slightly damaged the house with fire, but it was put out quickly and it's reparable/the damage isn't that severe?

Comment: It could mean that, but we wouldn't say it that way. You might say 'my kitchen was damaged by a fire'.